# Replicating Mongo schema enforcement across multiple database instances

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation

I'm running a NodeJS application that connects to a Mongo database. I've done the initial development with the [MongoClient](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html) library. I'm now learning however that without using an ORM like Mongoose, it is becoming increasingly harder to ensure the shape of the data is good. I found a nice thing in the Mongo documentation that indicates I can enforce a schema; one example looking like this:

```
db.createCollection("students", {
   validator: {
      $jsonSchema: {
         bsonType: "object",
         required: [ "name", "year", "major", "address" ],
         properties: {
            name: {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is required"
            },
            year: {
               bsonType: "int",
               minimum: 2017,
               maximum: 3017,
               description: "must be an integer in [ 2017, 3017 ] and is required"
            },
            major: {
               enum: [ "Math", "English", "Computer Science", "History", null ],
               description: "can only be one of the enum values and is required"
            },
            gpa: {
               bsonType: [ "double" ],
               description: "must be a double if the field exists"
            },
            address: {
               bsonType: "object",
               required: [ "city" ],
               properties: {
                  street: {
                     bsonType: "string",
                     description: "must be a string if the field exists"
                  },
                  city: {
                     bsonType: "string",
                     description: "must be a string and is required"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
})
```

and it solved my problems except if I were to spin up a new db instance (for instance using a Docker container). Wondering if anyone has any suggestions about how to copy validation across db instances or spin up a new one with it? I will rewrite the application at some point to use Mongoose (or other ORM) but in the mean time I'm looking for a solution to this problem using the `validator` on a schema.